# Translation of "tomate perita"

Tags: traducción, comida

I was reading [this recipe for Guiso Argentino](http://www.cocinerosargentinos.com/recetas/3/2238/Guisos/Guiso-carrero-tradicional.html) and came across the following line in the list of ingredients:

> Tomate perita 1 lata

Google translate gives me "adept" or "proficient" for "perita" and I know that "pera" means "pear", but none of these translations make sense.  In this context, what is the meaning of "tomate perita"?

Comment: Google's answer must be related to *perito* (n.): an expert in some field that can usually be consulted (e. g. in court) or relied upon for an informed opinion. Nothing to do with *pera*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Tomate perita" is one variety of tomato that takes its name after its shape resembling a pear.

I found some references in [elhuerto20](https://elhuerto20.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/tomates-de-pera/) and [gastronomía y cía](http://www.gastronomiaycia.com/2009/06/25/tomate-pera/).

> De marzo a julio aproximadamente, en tierras de climas cálidos se
>   recolecta el tomate pera, fruto híbrido de la tomatera que recibe este
>   nombre debido a su característica forma alargada y oblonga. De las
>   diferentes variedades que se cultivan de tomates pera, quizá el más
>   valorado es el conocido como Roma, al que le sigue el Rio Grande, cuyo
>   cultivo está más destinado a la productividad. Pero hay muchas otras
>   variedades, muy similares en aspecto, otras no tanto, incluso hay
>   tomates cherry pera y menos común, al menos en nuestra zona, es el
>   tomate pera amarillo.

In the article of Wikipedia of Tomato there is the section [Varieties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato#Varieties):

> Pear tomatoes are pear-shaped, and are based upon the [San Marzano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Marzano_tomato)
>   types for a richer gourmet paste.

Find one image here, taken from [frutaselporton](http://www.frutaselporton.es/apps/wa1/Hortalizas.html):

[image]

Comment: Would you know if "tomate perita" refers to the same variety as "Roma tomato" in English?

Comment: From the images in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roma_tomato they look very much alike. I am not an expert in tomatos (even though I love them) but I would say "yes, they do". And if they don't, they are almost brothers : )

Comment: Wait...it says right there in the description that you posted. How did neither of us see that?

Comment: Haha you are right!

Comment: *Tomates peritas* are not really pear-shaped; they're just not round (as you can see in the picture). I don't think they taste different from the others.